# this.Content is empty when trying change content in a usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls

So I have a Window class which changes this.Content on a button click:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CreateSessionWindow csw;
    RateSessionWindow rsw;
    CloseSessionWindow closesw;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        csw = new CreateSessionWindow();
        rsw = new RateSessionWindow();
        csw.setGoBackPage(rsw);
        closesw = new CloseSessionWindow();
    }

    private void bttnCreateSession_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        this.Content = new CreateSessionWindow();
    }
}
```

As you can see I pass another usercontroll to my usercontrolclass 'CreateSessionWindow'

In this class I have this:

```
public partial class CreateSessionWindow : UserControl
{
    RateSessionWindow mw;
    public CreateSessionWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void setGoBackPage(RateSessionWindow mw1) {
        mw = mw1;
    }

    private void bttnGoBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.Content = mw; //here it shows only a empty screen
    }    
}
```

So what I want is when I click on a button in the usercontroll wpf the content should change to RateSessionWindow but what happens is when I click on the button It only appears an empty screen. But it should show the elements of my RateSessionWindow class.

EDIT: I found out that the RateSessionWindow will only appear if I write :

```
this.Content = new RateSessionWindow();
```

but if I have a reference like now it won't work but why?...